# Redirect to Login if not authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an application with multiple modules under one domain. https://SomeDomain.es/

suppose I have modules module1 and module2, I can access the modules as
https://SomeDomain.es/module1

https://SomeDomain.es/module2

When I try to access above url it redirects me to login page if not authenticated.Where as If I try to access pages inside module1 then it does not redirect to login page. Rather it tries to serve the response by initializing the controller. The controller has a constructor which requires ICustomPrincipal as parameter and it is injected using **Unity IOC**. It fails when resolving the ICustomPrincipal since the Identity is null.

https://SomeDomain.es/module1 (redirects to login)

https://SomeDomain.es/module1/Profile/2 (does not redirect to login)

**Web.Config:**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".SomeLoginCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" protection="All" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
 </authentication>
```

I use custom authorize attribute which is marked on the controller

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public ICustomPrincipal customPrincipal;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorize = false;
        authorize = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if(!authorize)
            return false;

        if(!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        if(customPrincipal== null)
        {
            var factory = new PrincipalFactory(httpContext.User);
            customPrincipal= factory.CreatePrincipal();
        }

        if(customPrincipal.HasPermissions(function))
            authorize = true;
        else
            authorize = false;

        return authorize;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewName = "AccessDenied" };
                //new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

I have tested using **[Authorize]** attribute instead of custom one but no success.

I'm not sure what is the issue here. Please share your thoughts.

**Controller:**

```
[NoCache]
[CustomAuthorize(CustomFunction.Profile)]
public partial class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ICustomPrincipal Principal {get; set;}

    public ProfileController(ICustomPrincipal principal)
    {
        Principal = principal;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int Id)
    {
    }
}
```

**This is the case on timeout too.**

Comment: Can we see the code of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

When I use form authentication I set the authentication cookie with this method:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```